# Sed Copy Previous Field record if current is null

Tags: csv, sed

I have a csv or html with a table like this

```
Number Name ReportTo Time
11111 John Medical 0500
22222 Jane Dental 0700
                       Medical 1100
44444 Steve HR 0900
55555 Julie Training 0800
                       Records 1400
                       Business 1700
66666 David Medical 0800
```

I want to find a way to populate this table and eliminate all blank fields. 
The table should look like this:

```
Number Name ReportTo Time
11111 John Medical 0500
22222 Jane Dental 0700
22222 Jane Medical 1100
44444 Steve HR 0900
55555 Julie Training 0800
55555 Julie Records 1400
55555 Julie Business 1700
66666 David Medical 0800
```

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23505338/print-previous-row-if-current-is-blank) but with sed and from left
Thanks

Comment: How is the indentation achieved? Is this tab-delimited data with empty fields (i.e., tabs followed directly by other tabs) in some lines, or is there special formatting going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing anything more about the format, this awk should do:

```
awk 'NF == 4 { p1 = $1; p2 = $2; print } NF == 2 { print p1, p2, $1, $2 }' filename
```

That is:

```
NF == 4 {   # in a line with four fields
  p1 = $1   # remember the first two
  p2 = $2
  print     # print the line unchanged
}
NF == 2 {   # in a line with two fields
            # put the remembered fields before them.
  print p1, p2, $1, $2
}
```

Note that this assumes that the whole file consists of lines with either two or four fields; lines that do not fit this pattern will be silently dropped. If your file contains such lines, it is not obvious to me how you want them to be handled.

If you really want to do it with sed, then

```
sed '/^[[:space:]]/ { G; s/^[[:space:]]*\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2 \1/; p; d; }; h; s/[[:space:]]\+/\n/2; s/\n.*//; x' filename
```

works, but it is somewhat more convoluted:

```
/^[[:space:]]/ {                        # if a line begins with spaces, we
                                        # assume that front tokens are missing
  G                                     # get the remembered tokens from the
                                        # hold buffer
  s/^[[:space:]]*\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2 \1/  # put them before the tokens in this
                                        # line
  p                                     # print
  d                                     # and we're done.
}
h                                       # otherwise: Hold the line
s/[[:space:]]\+/\n/2                    # replace the second whitespace
                                        # sequence with \n
s/\n.*//                                # then remove it and everything after
                                        # it. This isolates the two first
                                        # fields in the line.
x                                       # swap that with the saved full line,
                                        # so the first two fields are in the
                                        # hold buffer for later use.

                                        # Dropping off the end leads to the
                                        # default action (printing), so the
                                        # full line is printed unchanged.
```

Comment: This is what I need thanks, the realy format was a html table one line per row  and the problem hapend whit 3st row the other 1 & 2 no meter if empty, ... etc.. litle more complicated but in escence  is te method used in your answer the final is: sed "/^[\s\t]*\(<\/*td>\)\{7\}/ {G;s/^[\s\t]*\(<\/*td>\)\{5\}\(.*\)\n\(.*\)$/\3<\/td><\/td>\2/;p; d};/^[\s\t]*\(<\/\?td>\)\{5\}[^<]\+/ { h; s/<\/td>/\n/3;s/\n.*//; x;}"